# How Do I Size My CSS Image At All Browser Sizes

Tags: jquery, css, image

I am a novice developer and am attempting my first project since completing my course (Omnifood - Udemy), therefore I am trying to rejig the Omnifood project into my own.

My problem is that I'm attempting to use a couple of cover images so that I can give the client a choice. However one of the images is stubbornly refusing to fit into the browser without being cropped.

This problem disappears when I scale the browser window down; which is making me think that maybe it's a Jquery thing. I'll paste my code and then the fixes I've tried and what happens during those fixes.

**Original Code** - Image cropped

```
header {
background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)), 
url(images/IMG_1650.jpg);
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
height: 100vh;
background-attachment: fixed;

}
```

**Fix #1** - 80% image now fits, however get tiling, use no repeat; to stop tiling, however now have whitespace all around page

```
header {
background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)), 
url(images/IMG_1650.jpg);
background-size: 80%;
background-position: center;
height: 100vh;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-repeat: no repeat;

}
```

**fix #2** - This gets the entire image in there, however now I have horizontal grey borders. This would work for me if my linear gradient stretched to cover the borders.

```
header {
background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)), 
url(images/IMG_1650.jpg);
background-size: contain;
background-position: center;
height: 100vh;
background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

I have also messed about with the height: vh to no avail. And I've resized the actual image in photo editor, and cropped it, also to absolutely no avail.

So I guess my questions are;

1. Can I get the image to fit nicely inside the page at full width?
2. Considering this problem happens when resizing the browser window, does that mean it's a Jquery thing?

[How it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzpSh.jpg)

[How it does look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDTE3.jpg)

Comment: Any chance you can provide a codepen or jsfiddle for this?

Comment: [Full Width background image](https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)
Please take a look at this artile

Comment: Hi Matt, I can, however my image doesn't show up on codepen, should I host the image somewhere like postimage first?

Comment: @Cryptogee Yes, if possible. :) Unless you can glean an answer from the article Harigovind posted of course!

Comment: Thank you Matt, I shall do both, I think the top answer in the article linked is the one; however I want to give a complete perspective on this so will link the codepen shortly.

Comment: OK, here's the pen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KyaqpK

Comment: you want to make image parallax with full width and height right

Comment: Hi Nikul, Yes I just want to be able to see the full image uncropped with no borders and my linear gradient unaffected.

Comment: if it is without parallax than its okay for you

Comment: I'm so sorry, I'm a complete noob, and I don't know what you mean when you say 'without parallax' please kindly explain.

Thanks

Comment: you added background-attachment: fixed; means you make image parallax

Comment: If I'm honest, I think the only issue you have here is that the image resolution will not work at all sizes, and this is actually the case for all images. You could add it in as an <img> tag, and have it display 100% width/height but it will knock the aspect ratio off, or you could resize it in photoshop, but that will still require some trimming. This image, at 800x640px (Aspect ratio: 1.25:1) will simply not stretch "nicely" to 1920x1080px (Aspect ratio: 1.78:1 (16:9))

Comment: Ah OK Matt, that makes total sense actually, thank you. It's good to know I'm not missing a simple command though! 

Cheers

Answer (score -1, accepted):

remove your header css  and add these css and try how it works

```
header {
background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)), url(https://s6.postimg.org/gv6ctlskh/IMG_1650_R.jpg);
height: 100vh;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center;
background-size: 100% 100%;}
```

Comment: Ah yes of course, I do want it to remain fixed like that, unfortunately the 100% 100% size simply stretches and distorts the image. I need it to have the correct aspect ratio.

Comment: if you get your answer accept my answer by click above right sign

Comment: I'm sorry I think I made a mistake, I double clicked above the sign, but it seemed to go negative, I have tried to correct by clicking the up arrow.

Although it doesn't solve my problem

Comment: OK don`t worry. try to  edit this also click on right sign see below these arrows